# Get-MsmqQueue does not find queues in cluster

Tags: powershell, cluster-computing, msmq

I have a 2 node cluster, on Windows Server 2012R2, version 4.0 of PowerShell installed.  One of the roles in the cluster is 'Messaging Queuing', named 'TESTMSMQ', which has about 20 private queues installed.

In a fresh PowerShell console, I set the environment variable _CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_ to be 'TESTMSMQ', using the command

```
$env:_CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_='TESTMSMQ'
```

When I run Get-MsmqQueue -Name *, I get nothing back.  But if I run compmgmt.msc I can see all the queues listed, and if I load the System.Messaging assembly into the PowerShell session, I can see the queues.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
[System.Messaging.MessageQueue]::Exists('.\private$\MyTestQueue')
```

returns True

Does anybody have an idea why the MSMQ cmdlets cannot find the queues, but the .net assembly can and the Computer Managment snap in sees the queues as well?

Just to be clear, there are no queues defined on the local node or physical nodes.  "private$\MyTestQueue" is only defined on the MSMQ installed role "TESTMSMQ".

So, if Exists() is returning True using a localhost name, then I would assume that the environment is the MSMQ role, not the physical node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little late, but I couldn't find the answer to this question anywhere. Maybe others are looking too...

Finally pieced together some ideas from a couple of places and got this working on Windows Server 2016.

On one of the cluster nodes:

```
$env:computername = "MsmqHostName"
Get-MsmqQueue | Format-Table -Property QueueName,MessageCount
```

remote from the cluster:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {$env:computername = "msmqHostName";Get-MsmqQueue | Format-Table -Property QueueName,MessageCount } -ComputerName ClusternNodeName
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me on 2019 as well - just set that $env:computername to the cluster name

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the classic clustered MSMQ problem.

[Clustering MSMQ applications – rule #1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2008/02/18/clustering-msmq-applications-rule-1/)

You don't specify where you are running your apps. For example, if "Exists('.\private$\MyTestQueue')" returns True then that means the MSMQ service is running locally to your test. So if you ran the test from the command prompt on a node, you are talking to MSMQ on the node - not the cluster. You would need to run the test from a clustered command prompt instead to use the clustered MSMQ service.

Comment: By setting the environment _CLUSTER_NETWORK_NAME_ am I not in a clustered command prompt?
*[Using PowerShell with Clustered MSMQ](http://www.winterdom.com/msmq/2011/10/25/using-powershell-with-clustered-msmq.html) 
*[GetHostNameW function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn793576(v=vs.85).aspx)